# Android: Set Edit text or text view id Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I am developing an application in which i am creating an Edittext programmatically as :

```
EditText edText = new EditText(this);
edText.setId(1);
edText .setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0f));
edText .setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
edText.setHint("dsgsdgsgs");
tableLayout.addView(edText);
```

Here I am setting the id of the Edit text as "1" by the line `edText.setId(1);` in integer.

But what i need is - I want to set the ID in character as for example:

```
edText.setId("edittext_hello");
```

So that i can access it via that id. How can i achieve this task please help.

Answer (score 25):

As the others have said you can't do this. Why do you want to / what's your requirement?

You could create an *id* in an xml file and use that - if you want it to be descriptive. This is also a better approach than using literal `int`s as you may get an *id* clash with other views in the layout hierarchy (unlikely but possible). This to me seems like the best / cleanest solution to your problem.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

e.g. in `res/values/id.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item
        type="id"
        name="edittext_hello" />
</resources>
```

and then set with

```
edText.setId(R.id.edittext_hello);
```

Comment: What if you have created elements dynamically according to a properties file? How can you set the IDs that are within the properties file dynamically to each one of the elements created?

Comment: Ok, I have figured out how. Just need to have the parent reference of the element you have set a tag, and then, you can find it with the tag. 
`LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.sale_aditionals_layout);`
and then 
`MaterialEditText materialEditText = (MaterialEditText) linearLayout.findViewWithTag(entry.getKey());`
for example..

Answer (score 4):

You can't set `id` with `char`, `String` or anything else except `int`...because, `id` is maintained by `R.java` file which contains only `int`.

You can use `setTag()` instead of `setId()`.

Use `setTag()` as below...

```
edText.setTag("edittext_hello");
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't set `id` as a String. You can only assign `integer` as Id. You can use `setTag()` of `View` with String. But for id it will only Integer. As android resources are maintained in R.java file for integer type.

**Update:**

**Why do you not set String or other data types (without integer) id to any android resource?**

**Because:**

An Android Resource id is a 32-bit integer. It comprises

```
an 8-bit Package id [bits 24-31]
an 8-bit Type id [bits 16-23]
a 16-bit Entry index [bits 0-15]
```

The **Package id** identifies the Package chunk which contains the Resource.

The **Type id** identifies the type of the Resource and hence the corresponding Typespec chunk and
Type chunk or chunks which contain its value or value(s)

The **Entry index** identifies the individual Resource within the Typespec chunk and Type chunk(s).

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Id

Answer (score 2):

You can also achieve your problem without creating any extra resource like ids.xml and without having any id set to any of the EditText created dynamically.

Just need to have the parent reference of the element you have set a tag, and then, you can find it with the tag.

**Parent**

`LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_id);`

and then

**Childs**

`EditText editText = (EditText) linearLayout.findViewWithTag("yourStringTag");`

for example..

Note: Obviously, if you have created EditTexts dynamically, you would do something like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : yourHashMap.entrySet()) {

LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout_id);

EditText editText = (EditText) linearLayout.findViewWithTag(entry.getKey());

// Then do whatever you want with your editText referenced.
// ...

}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use setText() instead of setId().

edText_view.setText("Your Text");

Comment: The question is about asking how to add id not text.