# Change ImageView in a GridView Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, gridview, imageview

I've set up a grid of ImageViews with TextView overlays. My ImageAdapter code is as follows:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView)grid.findViewById(R.id.mastery_text);

        imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.mastery_image);
        grid.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        grid.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        grid.setBackgroundResource(R.color.orange);

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);            

    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }

    return grid;
}
```

The corresponding XML layout for my ImageAdapter is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_practitioner" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/mastery_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#bbffffff"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" >

        <TextView android:id="@+id/mastery_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:text="3/3"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

XML code for my GridView (activity class):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the onCreate method of my main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_masteries);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Masteries.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I want to, after initializing the grid with the images, change one of the ImageViews from my activity class, given its position on the grid. How would I do that?

I'm *not* asking to change the image in response to an onItemClick. 
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I'm thinking of creating a `changeImage(int position, int imageId)` method in my Adapter and calling that from my activity class. Is that the right approach?

Comment: change the image in adapter and call `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: How do you get a specific ImageView from the grid given its position? I'm thinking of creating a `changeImage(int position, int imageId)` method in my Adapter and calling that from my activity class.

Comment: You will be having an list of images write? If yes you can update imageId on that position and call `notifyDatasetChanged`

Comment: Can you show me in code?

`imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);` occurs once for each position on the grid right? How can you _go back_ to the first imageview and change its content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter:

```
public void updateImage(int position, int resourceId)
{
    mThumbIds[position] = resourceId;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

In your activity:

```
mAdapter.updateImage(<position>, <image_resource_id>);
```

**Notes**

1. You will have to make the adapter a member of your activity
2. The main idea is that you modify the backing data and and notify the `GridView` that this has changed and it is time to be redrawn
3. Your `getView()` method implementation needs a lot of improvement. It will cause lots of bugs once the system starts recycling the views (the `convertView` parameter comes in != null for a position different than it was used for last time)

Here's a sketch of how your getView() should look like:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image, parent, false);
        // next three lines would not be necessary if:
        //  a) it is the same for every item;
        //  b) you inflate properly (using the parent);
        //  c) you specify this in the item's xml (R.layout.image)
        convertView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
        convertView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_red_light);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.mTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mastery_text);
        viewHolder.mImageView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.mastery_image);
        // this could also be set in xml perhaps
        viewHolder.mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    // update the values every time we are being asked to update the item,
    // because the item might have been reused from a different position
    viewHolder.mImageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    //viewHolder.mTextView.setText("myText");

    return convertView;
}


public static class ViewHolder
{
    TextView mTextView;
    ImageView mImageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a unique id to each ImageView using names (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527883/android-set-edit-text-or-text-view-id-programmatically)) or even integer numbers with a sequence or something (increasing at each image you put in the view).

Another good way to do this is using the tags, with `setTag()` and `getTag()`.
This question has a good answer: [What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

Comment: It's not working, I keep getting NullPointerException when I do something with the ImageView I got from `findViewWithTag`.